# How to apply X3D clipPlane to only one object in the scene without affecting others?

Tags: three.js, x3d, x3dom, vrml

I am working on an application using X3D and would like to apply a clipping plane (clipPlane) to only one object in my scene, without affecting other objects. However, it seems that when I define a clipPlane, it affects the entire scene.

Is there any way to specify that the clipPlane should be applied only to a specific object in the scene, while the other objects remain unaffected?

Here is a simplified example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPPHN.png)

The yellow line represents the clipPlane, would have a way to aplied the clip plane only for red cube, but not for the blue esphere and green cone?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a clipping plane to a material and then use the respective material *only* for the red cube.

The material property you want to configure is [Material.clippingPlanes](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/Material.clippingPlanes).

When using clipping planes on object level like explained above, you have to set the `localClippingEnabled` property of `WebGLRenderer` to `true`.